# jquery toggleClass on appended class

Tags: jquery, hover, append

I have a dynamically generated table which is created via ajax request and appended to the page. I require the background to change when the user hovers over each cell. (This is not a html table - the table is generated through css therefore no   etc...).

My code so far is as follows.

```
$(document).on('hover', '.day_holder1a', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('forum_hover');
});
```

I believe the problem is with 'this' and it's reference to $(document) but my alterations have not been successful.

I have removed the dot before forum_hover in the toggleClass as this was an error on my part and should have checked the code I pasted.

Answer (score 3):

No the problem is not with `this` object.

The problem is with `.` in your toggleClass function

```
$(document).on('hover', '.day_holder1a', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('forum_hover');
});
```

NOTE: instead of `hover` use `mouseenter`

Comment: Actually the dot in the pasted code was not originally there - my error - should have checked the code before pasting - unfortunately this still does not solve the problem. I will try an put something similar up on jsfiddle

Comment: OK THEN USE MOUSEENTER IN PLACE OF HOVER AND PASTE THE FIDDLE

Comment: unfortunately jsfiddle is timing out at the moment - will return to it later. Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mdVZk/6/ although this seems to work as desired. Possibly the problem is with my class identifiers which I will go through now.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `.` on the toggleClass function.
Read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)